# How to replace string with character ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

is there a way where I can replace multiple strings e.g.. hot , cold , good, with ###?

**The text field**

```
div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Comment, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Comment, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Comment, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
<div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Controller**

```
     public ActionResult Create()
    {

        return View(new Charity());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,DisplayName,Date,Amount,Comment")] Charity charity)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Donations.Add(charity);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Additionalinfo", "Charities");
        }
        return View(charity);
    }
```

**Model**

```
public class Charity
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z]+$", ErrorMessage = "Use letters only please")]
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    [Range(2, Int32.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Atleast £2.00 or a whole number please")]
    public int Amount { get; set; }
    public Double TaxBonus { get; set; }
    public String Comment { get; set; }
}
```

Can I replace multiple texts with one code function or does it have to be individually for each string?? I am new to MVC and ASP.NET so pretty confusing.

Comment: Are you asking whether you can replace some words in `Comments` field? You surely can. At what point do you want to do that?

Comment: Yes thats what I am asking for sorry for not clarifying enough, what do you mean by what point? basically how can I replace the words like 'hot' , 'cold'  when inputted in the comment field with '###'?

Comment: You can replace them inside the controller or you can replace them inside the view itself. For an example, if you want to replace these words when user is typing them, you have to use javascript to do that.

Comment: @KosalaW not exactly when theyre typing, I want it to occur after they pressed the 'submit' button and if the words entered is the word being replaced it displays as '###' under the comment colomn in the database.

Comment: You can do that in your controllers `HttpPost` method. (The method that gets executed when you submit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can do that in your controller.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,DisplayName,Date,Amount,Comment")] Charity charity)
{

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(charity.Comment)
        {
           var comment = charity.Comment.ToLower().Replace("hot","###").Replace("cold","###");
           charity.Comment = comment;
        }
        db.Donations.Add(charity);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Additionalinfo", "Charities");
    }
    return View(charity);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for yyour help:)